# Target child of children with .each() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m iterating through the elements and grabbing the `src` attribute of the child of that element. I have this HTML code:

```
<noscript data-alt="super awesome">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8585847956_39864361e3.jpg" alt="something" />
</noscript>
<noscript data-alt="super awesome">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8235/8585847956_39864361e3.jpg" alt="something" />
</noscript>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('body').children().each(function() {
  var noscriptTag = $(this)[0];

  var imgAlt = noscriptTag.getAttribute("data-alt");
  var img_src = noscriptTag.find('img');
  var img_regular = img_src.getAttribute("src");
  console.log(img_regular);
});
```

But I’m getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'find'
```

I also tried various other combinations (like `$(this).find('img');`) without making it work.

Here’s the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LjWhw/

How do I target the `img` tag of that element? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:** You can’t target elements which are inside `<noscript>` with JavaScript.

Comment: FYI, `var noscriptTag = $(this)[0];` is the same as `var noscriptTag = this;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call find jQuery function on DOM object, Use `jQuery` object instead of `DOM` javascript object to call find on it.

*Change*

```
var noscriptTag = $(this)[0];
```

*To*

```
var noscriptTag = $(this);
```

**Edit:** You will also need to change the code accordingly e.g. `img_src.getAttribute("src");` to  `img_src[0].getAttribute("src");` or  `img_src.attr("src");`

Comment: then I’m getting a different error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getAttribute'`. Should I change it to `attr("src");` as well?

Comment: Yes Alex you can to  img_src[0].getAttribute("src"); or img_src[0].attr("src")

Comment: Thanks Adil. But I’m still getting an `undefined`. It looks like it’s not finding the `img`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dCGjI

Comment: I think problem is with noscript tag if I change it with div, it works, http://jsfiddle.net/Kv9bV/

Comment: Yeah, most probably jQuery does not `read` elements inside `<noscript>`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do it this way:

```
$('body').children().each(function() {
  var noscriptTag = $(this).find('noscript').first();
   //---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----this way
  var imgAlt = noscriptTag.getAttribute("data-alt");
  var img_src = noscriptTag.find('img');
  var img_regular = img_src.attr("src");
  console.log(img_regular);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/UQJsy/1/

```
$('noscript').each(function () {
    var noscriptTag = $(this);

    var imgAlt = noscriptTag.attr("data-alt");
    var img_src = noscriptTag.children('img');
    var img_regular = img_src.attr("src");
    alert(imgAlt);
});
```

Comment: Please do not only post code. Also explain the differences and why it solves the problem.

Comment: I don’t want the `alt`, I want the `src` which alerts `undefined`.

Comment: i think noscript is used when browser doesn't support javascript. in that case would you be able to execute what you trying to???? Because if browser supports script anything inside noscript will not be rendered. please correct if im wrong.